# What are the side effects of firing PropertyChanged not in UI thread?

Tags: .net, wpf

If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you could raise event in non-UI thread - should i avoid this and why?

**Update:** It is about binding in wpf application.

Comment: Have you been able to sucesfully call NotifyPropertyChanged from a non UI thread? By design only the thread that created the UI object can access the object. The common usage is to create the expensive object in the background and then in the callback (on the UI tread) bind the object or call NotifyPropertChanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you should not avoid this. WPF marshals `PropertyChanged` events to the UI thread on your behalf, but even if it did not, it is likely not the component's responsibility to do so.

UPDATE: I slightly misinterpreted your question. For some reason I thought you were asking specifically about background components not directly related to UI.

If your component is intended for direct consumption by the UI, then it may make sense to marshal changes to the UI thread, such as with Windows Forms. However, if the component is UI agnostic, it does not generally make sense, although if necessary you can switch to the UI thread in an agnostic fashion by using the current `SynchronizationContext`.

I do marshalling as and when needed with WPF, because as I stated normally you don't need to since WPF does it for you. But if you're changing collections too then you will need to, since such changes are not automatically marshalled.

Comment: Introduced in .NET 4.5 the BindingOperations class has a static EnableCollectionSynchronization method that allows you to associate a lock-object with an ObservableCollection (more exactly and IEnumerable instance). This informs the binding mechanism to lock during enumeration in the view (refreshing the view contents) when binding to an itemssource. So now, binding to collections updated on non-UI threads won't be a problem eiter (as long as you use the same lock when you alter or observe the collection inside the viewmodel). Finally I've got rid of the Dispatcher in my viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data-binding, this may cause the binding framework to encounter exceptions. For example, the winforms bindings are **not** expecting this, and will typically get into trouble.

It depends on the framework though; maybe (I gebuinely don't know) WPF supports this, for example.

Comment: WPF does support this which is very convenient.